# Over Sampling Method

Tags: machine-learning

In oversampling method we replicate the  minority elements and augment it to the set again back. But how does this increase the cardinality of the set as, a set can have unique elements.

Answer (score 0):

Well, we often use the term "dataset" in ML even for objects that are not - mathematically speaking - sets i.e. elements are not distinct.